# Trouble Loading and Saving Settings with Tkinter and Pickle

Tags: python, tkinter, pickle

I wrote a simple script to plot some data generated by an instrument, and I'd like to add a few display customization options. As a first pass, I added a "width" and "height" fields for the output plots, which I store in a class called 'Settings'. I would like to read those settings in (if they exist) and display them, allow the user to change them, and save them on program close. However, right now when I run the code, change the width from the default 7 to another value, and close the program, my debug statements report:

```
settings loaded: 
7
closing:
7
```

The relevant sections of my code are as follow:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure as Figure
import pickle 
import os

#create settings
settings = {
    'chartWidth': 7,
    'chartHeight': 5
    }
settingsfile = 'settings.pk' 

#... plotting functions

def exit():
    mode = 'ab' if os.path.exists(settingsfile) else 'wb'
    with open(settingsfile, mode) as f:
        pickle.dump(settings, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
        print('closing:')
        print(settings['chartWidth'])
    window.destroy()

                                                                                          
# Create the root window
window = tk.Tk()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(window, width = 400, height = 200,  relief = 'raised', bg='white')
canvas1.pack()
  
window.wm_title('Table Plotting')  
      
button_getFile = tk.Button(window,
                        text = "Plot File", fg='white', bg='black',
                        command = plotFile)
  
button_exit = tk.Button(window,
                     text = "Exit", fg='white', bg='black',
                     command = exit)

label_Width = tk.Label(window, text = "Image Width: ", bg="white")
settings['chartWidth'] = tk.Entry(window, width=5)
settings['chartWidth'].insert(-1, settings['chartWidth'])

label_Height = tk.Label(window, text = "Image Height: ", bg="white")
settings['chartHeight'] = tk.Entry(window, width=5)
settings['chartHeight'].insert(-1, settings['chartHeight'])
  
canvas1.create_window(50, 25, window=label_Width)
canvas1.create_window(110, 25, window=settings['chartWidth'])
canvas1.create_window(250, 25, window=label_Height)
canvas1.create_window(310, 25, window=settings['chartHeight'])

canvas1.create_window(175, 50, window=button_getFile)
canvas1.create_window(175, 80, window=button_exit)

try:
    with open(settingsfile, 'rb') as f:
        try:
            settings = pickle.load(f)
            print('settings loaded: ')
            print(settings['chartWidth'])
        except: 
            pass
except:
    pass
     

# Let the window wait for any events
window.mainloop()
```

When I run the program, the default values are not filled: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vX03I.jpg

If I comment out the `settings['chartWidth'].insert(-1, settings['chartWidth'])` line, the input fields are blank rather than being populated by the default values.

And as mentioned above, the altered settings['chartWidth'] never seems to be saved. Could someone please give me some pointers about how to get the proper read/write behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have overwritten the values inside `settings` by `Entry` widgets:

```py
settings['chartWidth'] = tk.Entry(window, width=5)
...
settings['chartHeight'] = tk.Entry(window, width=5)
```

Use other variables like below:

```py
e_width = tk.Entry(window, width=5)
e_width.insert(-1, settings['chartWidth'])
...
e_height = tk.Entry(window, width=5)
e_height.insert(-1, settings['chartHeight'])
...
canvas1.create_window(110, 25, window=e_width)
...
canvas1.create_window(310, 25, window=e_height)
```

Also you need to update `settings` before saving inside `exit()` function (better use another function name because `exit()` is a built-in function) and overwrite the pickle file always (not using append mode when the file exists):

```py
def exit():
    try:
        settings['chartWidth'] = int(e_width.get())
        settings['chartHeight'] = int(e_height.get())

        #mode = 'ab' if os.path.exists(settingsfile) else 'wb'
        with open(settingsfile, "wb") as f:
            pickle.dump(settings, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
            print('closing:')
            print(settings['chartWidth'])
        window.destroy()
    except ValueError as e:
        print("Invalid value:", e)
```

Finally you need to load the pickle file before creating the `Entry` widgets, otherwise the default values are always used as the initial text in those `Entry` widgets.